# How include hash (#) in drupal_goto path?

Tags: redirection

Is there any way to include a # in drupal_goto?

i want something like this

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  switch ($node->type) {
    case 'product':      
      drupal_goto("products#".$node->nid);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For Drupal 6,

It should be 3rd parameter

```
drupal_goto($path = '', $query = NULL, $fragment = NULL, $http_response_code = 302)

drupal_goto("products", NULL, $node->nid);
```

For Drupal 7

```
drupal_goto($path = '', array $options = array(), $http_response_code = 302)
drupal_goto("products", array('fragment' => $node->nid));
```

Comment: for D7 example, you can use any parameter that url() function supports... such as URL params.

Answer (score 7):

In Drupal 6 drupal_goto use its third parameter for the fragmentation. If you wants to make the url like products#345 you should pass its fragment as third argument in drupal_goto function.

```
drupal_goto("products", NULL, $node->nid); // where $node->nid is the fragment.
```

In Drupal 7 you should pass fragment as key value pair of array on second parameter of drupal_goto function.

```
drupal_goto('products', array('fragment' => $node->nid)) ; // where $node->nid is the fragment.
```

Both of above will produce an url like products#123, where 123 is the value of $node->nid variable.

Answer (score 2):

This also worked for me in Drupal 7

```
 drupal_goto( '/products/' . 'section', array( 'fragment' =>  'subsection', 'alias' => TRUE ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

drupal_goto loses #zzz if there is a ?destination=foobar#zzz, as this is never returned by $_SERVER, remove this line as does nothing apart from breaking stuff:

```
//$options['fragment'] = $destination['fragment'];  // removed
is the same as 
$options['fragment']='';
```